# How can I listen for events in my activity waiting for a computation to finish?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback

I have a main activity which needs to listen for the results of computation on an audio stream so.
Here's the main activity

```
private void setSoundProcessListener() {
    SoundProcess object = new SoundProcess(music_stream1, music_stream2);
    
    object.setSoundProcessListener(new SoundProcessListener.SoundProcessListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataLoaded(String data) {
            // I want this to get called every time I complete processing a piece of sound
            do something...
        }
    });
}
```

How can I create a SoundProcess class that calls another function asynchronously so that each time a piece of sound from the stream is processed(some analytical function) successfully I get the results of that computation?

Sound Processor Class:

```
public SoundProcess(music_stream1, music_stream2) {
    process sound.... on complete return the resulting data to the main activity listener aand continue processing more sound from the streams
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an interface having a function which will be a callback function in your activity.
implement that interface in your activity..

In your SoundProcess class,

declare a member variable :

```
  SPInterface ac ;//SPInterface is name of the interface.
```

inside the function in SoundProcessor class, where u will get to know the sound processing will complete,write :

```
 ac = (MainActivity)activity
 ac.fun1()
```

//fun1() is the function of the interface which you will be having in ur activity to get your activity notified that the processing is complete.You must have a reference to activity object in ur soundProcessor Class.Dont declare it as a member variable else it may lead to potential memory leaks.